Prebid Server sends all metrics as zeroes
I have a prebid server, which runs nicely.
I have to investigate quite high number of timeouts, and I think metrics would help.
The issue is, while metrics collection seems to be running (from pprof and some debugging), all metrics are always zero. I've tried that with both Influx and Prometheus
Searching over the internet, I didn't find anything that can shed light on why they're always zero.
Influx is getting all the metrics, and I can see them fed into it, but all values are zero.
For Prometheus, it's the same. When I directly curl the collection endpoint on the Prebid server, I can see a list of all metrics with zero values.
I am using Go version
